# how to dynamically render template content

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I'm current doing a meteorjs site. However, I have a problem of rendering the content of the site correct.(Because I have a fixed sidebar).

**//layout.html**

```
<head>
  <title>App</title>
</head>

<body>
    //render helper
    {{renderPage layout}}
</body>
```

**//route.js**

```
  Meteor.Router.add({
    '/': 'index',
    '/admin': 'admin',
    '/search': 'search',
    '/contact': 'contact',
    '/login':'login',
    '/logout':'logout',
    '/registration': 'registration',
    '/admin/listUser': 'listUser',
    '/admin/addUser': 'addUser',
    '/admin/editUser': 'editUser',
    '/admin/delUser': 'delUser',
    '/admin/listPost': 'listPost',
    '/admin/addPost': 'addPost',
    '/admin/editPost': 'editPost',
    '/admin/delPost': 'delPost',
    '/admin/viewPost': 'viewPost',
    '/admin/modPost': 'modPost',
    '/admin/listLoc': 'listLoc',
    '/admin/addLoc': 'addLoc',
    '/admin/delLoc': 'delLoc',
  })

  // to determin which page to render
  Template.body.helpers({
    layout: function() {
      switch (Meteor.Router.page()) {
        case 'index':
          return 'index';
        case 'admin':
          return 'admin';
        case 'login':
          return 'login';
        case 'logout':
          return 'logout';
        case 'registration':
          return 'registration';
        case 'search':
          return 'search';
        case 'contact':
          return 'contact';
        default:
          return 'index';
      }
    }
  });
```

**admin.html**

```
//sidebar
<template name="adminSide">
<ul class="nav nav-list">
    <li class="nav-header">User Management</li>
    <li><a href="/admin/listUser" id="linkValue">List Users</a></li>

    <li class="nav-header">Posting Management</li>
    <li><a href="/admin/listPost">List Posting</a></li>
    <li><a href="/admin/addPost">Add New Posting</a></li>
    <li><a href="/admin/modPost">Moderate Posting</a></li>

    <li class="nav-header">Location Management</li>
    <li><a href="/admin/listLoc">List Locations</a></li>
    <li><a href="/admin/addLoc">Add New Locations</a></li>

    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="/logout">Log Out</a></li>
    </ul>
</template>

//landing page
<template name="adminLand">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Welcome to the Admin Panel!</h1>
    </div>
        <p class="lead">To begin, click on any link on the left.</p>
</template>

//page to render if click on sidebar
<template name="listUser">
</template>

<template name="admin">
  {{> navigationAdm}}
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="span3">
       {{>adminSide}}
    </div>
    <div class="span9">
       //how do I make this render another template when the sidebar is clicked?
       {{renderPage}}
    </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    {{>footer}}
</div>
</template>
```

I'm using Router from Meteorite. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the router from meteorite you need to make a file with your routes:

**client/router.js**

```
Meteor.Router.add({
    '/admin': 'adminLand',
    '/admin/listUser':'listUser',
    '/admin/listPost':'listPost',
    '/admin/addPost':'addPost',
    '/admin/modPost':'modPost'
    '*': 'not_found'
});
```

Then you need to create a region in your page where you want the content to come to with `{{renderPage}}`

```
<div class="span9">
   //how do I make this render another template when the sidebar is clicked?
   {{renderPage}}
</div>
```

Then just create templates for each 'route', you've already done `adminLand`

**your html file**

```
<template name="listUser">
    <h2> List users</h2>
</template>

<template name="listPost">
    <h2> List posts</h2>
</template>

<template name="addPost">
    <h2> Add Post</h2>
</template>

<template name="modPost">
    <h2> Mod Post</h2>
</template>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to loop my templates
 {{#each template}}
  {{renderPage}}
   {{/each}}
but how do I loop my templates when all my templates have different names and won't that render all the templates at once?

Comment: You don't have to loop your templates. Use the above arrangement as is & the router will match up the url to whatever a template is called via `<template name=` and what is defined in the `Meteor.Router.add` as the URL & it will show only that one specific template at `{{renderPage}}`, which is defined via Meteor Router.

Comment: I did exactly but it only loads the whole page but not the side bar.

Comment: Could you provide more of your html file? I'm not too sure why its not there there might be more than one renderPage or the sidebar isn't being included in the core html somehow

Comment: I've edited the codes and added more html file. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Change `<body>
    //render helper
    {{renderPage layout}}
</body>` to `<body>{{>admin}}</body>`

Comment: Hi, its works now for my admin side, but my client view is messed up as my client view does not need the sidebar